# i was caught cheating in my exam, I know it's wrong and I know I'm not stupid, it's just that how should I deal with it?

Tags: cheating

I didn't really study much for the exam because I overslept due to hormones and I know it is not an excuse but anyway during the exam, my class mate passed me a paper with answers in it and by the way it was my first time to do this kind of cheating so I just go with it for the following reasons:

1.) So that my grade in the exam will be much more higher;

2.) and to make my COLLEGE life much more memorable (which is ridiculous).

Then eventually my teacher caught me for I was awkward and a NEWBIE to this thingy and "oh my god" he deducted 20 points in my test paper!(meaning that I could get a negative score! I don't even know if my score is more than 20 points already) and my reaction to it was I laughed it off and accepted my mistake but deep inside it felt like i could die out of embarrassment. Thank God he didn't tell all of my classmates of what I did.

What should I do? My next class is on Monday, 7 in the morning. Should I just skip class to wait for all the embarrassments to go all away? I know I will take all the responsibilities of this action but I think it is not enough for my dignity because I know if I studied i could've got a decent score and would've not cheated (of course).

**PLEASE HELP MEEEEEE ):)**

Comment: Note for future reference: when interacting with academics online or in person, it may be worth doing so in more formal phrasing before proceeding to OMG LOL etc

Comment: Channel your shame into constructive action.  Scrub the kitchen floor.  Weed the garden.  Study for the exam you just took.  Prepare for Monday's class.  Write an apology letter to your professor (not an email).  Say that you won't do it again, and mean it.

Comment: I would like to think graduates are smart and experienced enough to never attempt to cheat, but that is unrealistic. Why is this not a question that "can also apply to graduate or post-graduate academicians"?

Comment: I agree with @PatriciaShanahan. Though formulated in a somewhat childish way, this could be a valid question also for graduates, taking also into account the variability of graduate studies around the world. However, the OP can try to formulate their question in a more mature way: this could help their personal interactions with the faculties too.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Graduate students most certainly cheat, as evidenced by some of the other questions that we get.  Their reasons and thinking regarding it tend to be different, however.  Beyond that, the question has more problems than just being about an undergraduate: I would not like to see it reopened without being edited to address those.

Comment: I never knew that academia.SE is also meant for such questions. strange!

Answer (score 6):

Practical advice: no further action is required from you. It sounds like the punishment has already been decided and enacted, and to be honest it was fairly lenient. At most, you should apologize to your professor (without giving any excuses (and especially not the ones you've given here)) and promise that it won't happen again. But the main thing is to simply not cheat in the future.

General advice: your sense of embarrassment toward your teacher is appropriate. Use it as motivation to work hard and show that you can succeed honestly. This means going to class even though you feel awkward. This will also be good practice for the working world: you don't get to stay home from your job because you're embarrassed about a recent screw-up.